# What stops the import of the rule contained in my custom module?

Tags: rules

I have exported rules from the existing rules and I wanted to import rule using custom module. But when I enable this module. Rules weren't imported in rules list.

I created 3 files:

1) `my_module.INFO` file:

```
name = My module example
description = My module for import rules
core = 7.x
package = My module
```

2) `my_module.MODULE` file (blank file):

```
<?php
```

3) `my_module.rules_defaults.INC` file:

```
<?php
     function rules_example_default_rules_configuration() {
      $configs = array();
      $rule = '{ "rules_final_save_pdfs" : {
        "LABEL" : "final save pdfs",
        "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
        "ACTIVE" : false,
        "OWNER" : "rules",
        "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "views_pdf", "entityform" ],
        "ON" : { "entityform_insert" : [] },
        "IF" : [
          { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entityform" ], "field" : "field_test_pdf_form" } }
        ],
        "DO" : [
          { "views_pdf_rules_action_save" : {
              "views_pdf" : "test_new_view:pdf_1",
              "path" : "\/workout\/sites\/default\/files\/test_pdfs\/[entityform:field-date]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }';
      $configs['rules_final_save_pdfs'] = rules_import($rule);
      return $configs;
    }
?>
```

Please let me know if there any changes to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is for D7, try this variation of the your code in your item "3)":

```
<?php
     function my_module_default_rules_configuration() {
      $configs = array();
      $rule = '{ "rules_final_save_pdfs" : {
        "LABEL" : "final save pdfs",
        "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
        "ACTIVE" : false,
        "OWNER" : "rules",
        "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "views_pdf", "entityform" ],
        "ON" : { "entityform_insert" : [] },
        "IF" : [
          { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "entityform" ], "field" : "field_test_pdf_form" } }
        ],
        "DO" : [
          { "views_pdf_rules_action_save" : {
              "views_pdf" : "test_new_view:pdf_1",
              "path" : "\/workout\/sites\/default\/files\/test_pdfs\/[entityform:field-date]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }';
      $configs['rules_final_save_pdfs'] = entity_import('rules_config', $rule);
      return $configs;
    }
?>
```

Note the changes in the line with ***function ...*** (near the top) and the line with ***entity_import*** (near the end).

**Be aware**: if I try to import your rule (= the string contained in `$rule`) in a site of mine (where I don't have `views_pdf` module enabled), and using the Rules UI, I get an import error like so:

> Import failed.
>
> Missing the required module views_pdf.

That makes sense of course (since I don't have that module). So check that that is not the case why your rule isn't imported (same for `entityform`). A possible technique to prevent this issue, is to declare those 2 modules as a dependency in your `my_module.info` file.

PS: have a look at the code of the [Answers Userpoints](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/answers/tree/answers_userpoints) module for an example where this technique is used also.

Comment: Do we have to do any other changes in module [ my_module.MODULE ] file?